# python etree elementpath syntax

Tags: python, elementtree

I've some bigs problems for editing odt file in python. I've choosen etree way, but understanding the elementpath syntax is quite hard.
I've saw somewhere that text in nodes ARE nodes too in xml with xpath syntax, but I'm not sure elementpath consider it as node...
Well, I'm lost...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import StringIO
from lxml import etree
xmldata = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-content xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" >
<text:span text:style-name="T2">water is good</text:span>
<text:span text:style-name="T3">#QUALITE#</text:span>
<text:span text:style-name="T2">#AUTEUR#</text:span>
<text:span text:style-name="T2">#QUALITE#</text:span>
<text:span text:style-name="T4">#AUTEUR#</text:span>
<text:p text:style-name="P14"></text:p>
</document-content>
'''

fakefile = StringIO.StringIO(xmldata)
root = etree.parse(fakefile).getroot()
fakefile.close()
nspace = {}
nspace["t"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
query = root.find('.//t:span[@t:style-name="T2"]', nspace)
print query.text
```

How can I modify the find request for selecting the node with #AUTEUR# text ?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of following codes:

```
for query in root.xpath('.//t:span[contains(text(),"#AUTEUR#")]', namespaces=nspace):
    print query.text
```

OR

```
for query in root.xpath('.//t:span[text()="#AUTEUR#"]', namespaces=nspace):
    print query.text
```